# Why do I need to cast IDictionary<T, HashSet<S>> to IDictionary<T, IEnumerable<S>>?

Tags: c#, dictionary, casting, type-inference

The following code is valid since `HashSet` implements `IEnumerable`:

```
IEnumerable<TEdge> edges = new HashSet<TEdge>();
```

But I get a compile error if I try to use the same as typed values in a Dictionary:

```
IDictionary<TVertex, IEnumerable<TEdge>> vertexEdges = 
    new Dictionary<TVertex, HashSet<TEdge>>();
```

> `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TVertex,System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<TEdge>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary<TVertex,System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TEdge>>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

What am I missing here? Surely the compiler should be able to figure this out so I'm guessing there either has to be some meaningful decision behind the restriction or I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: This question should NOT be closed and the close vote should be retracted.  This is a perfectly valid question that shows effort to understand what is going behind the scenes as well as enough information to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because an `IDictionary<TVertex, HashSet<TEdge>>` is NOT a `Dictionary<TVertex, IEnumerable<TEdge>>`.  If it were, you could add a value that is some other collection of `TEdge` other than a `HashSet`.

Similarly, you can't cast a `List<Cat>` to a `List<IAnimal>`, otherwise you could add a `Dog` to the list.

Also note that a cast will fail at runtime.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I hadn't thought of the problem with the add method. I far as I understand this is a problem of covariance? ^_^

Comment: Also, you're completely right, the cast does fail at runtime.

Answer (score 2):

The following code will work:

```
IDictionary<TVertex, IEnumerable<TEdge>> vertexEdges =
    new Dictionary<TVertex, IEnumerable<TEdge>>();
```

Here's why the code you had wouldn't work. Your vertexEdges would allow this code:

```
IEnumerable<TEdge> list = new List<TEdge>();
vertexEdges.Add(vert, list);
```

This would appear valid, because list is an IEnumerable. However, vertexEdges can only store HashSets, not IEnumerables.

You have to make a decision: if you want all of the contained types to be hashsets, change your vertexEdges decleration to explicitly use HashSets. If you don't care what kind of IEnumerable you store, have your dictionary be of IEnumerable. If you do, it's valid to add Lists or Hashsets to your dictionary.

If you have already existing dictionary, and you'd like to convert it to the generic one, you can instantiate a new Dictionary with Linq:

```
Dictionary<TVertex, HashSet<TEdge>> oldDict = 
       new Dictionary<TVertex, HashSet<TEdge>>();
IDictionary<TVertex, IEnumerable<TEdge>> vertexEdges = oldDict
       .Select(k => 
          new KeyValuePair<TVertex, IEnumerable<TEdge>(k.Key, k.Value))
       .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, k => k.Value);
```

The real downside to this method is you are creating a new dictionary.

Comment: Nice of you to mention the example of converting between dictionaries using Linq. =P